# Error: no main manifest attribute, in matlab.jar

Tags: matlab, manifest, mainclass

I installed MATLAB on Fedora and tried to run it using `java -jar matlab.jar`,
but I got this error:

> `no main manifest attribute, in matlab.jar`

I read somewhere to make a manifest file with below content:

```
Main-Class: MainClass
```

but when I ran `java -jar matlab` again I got this error:

> `Error: Could not find or load main class MainClass`

How do I resolve this issue?